# Infix (%>%) operator with paste0

Tags: r, magrittr

So I want to stack strings in `%>% way`. Say, I have a character vector

```
names <- c("Alice","Bob","Charles")
```

and a string:

```
phrase <- "Name is "
```

A usual way to do this is with `paste0`:

```
> paste0(phrase, names)
[1] "Name is Alice"   "Name is Bob"     "Name is Charles"
```

Is there a way to do this with `%>%`? I am able to concatenate these only in reversed order:

```
> names %>% paste0(phrase)
[1] "AliceName is "   "BobName is "     "CharlesName is "
```

Comment: Use `names %>% paste0(phrase, .)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
phrase %>% paste0(names)
```

Which gives

```
[1] "Name is Alice"   "Name is Bob"     "Name is Charles"
```

Or, you can access the LHS by using `.`:

```
names %>% paste0(phrase, .)
```

Which also returns:

```
[1] "Name is Alice"   "Name is Bob"     "Name is Charles"
```